# does iphone automatically save the coordinate when taking photo

Tags: iphone, dictionary, gps, photo, coordinate

Does iPhone/ipad automatically save the coordinate when the user take a photo. The reason I am asking is that when I import my photo into iPhoto in Mac, it can be seen where I took this photo, even I am traveling internationally without signal. I think this is a very cool function. I am considering develop an app which is like iPhoto, users can see where they took the photo on the map. Any suggestion and answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `CLLocationManager` for get Curent location and add this location with photo detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does iPhone/ipad automatically save the coordinate when the user take a photo.

(`Error: expected '?', found '.'`...)

Well, this depends on whether the user has enabled this function. If the Photo app doesn't have permission to access the location of the user, then it doesn't geotag the images. Otherwise it does.